# OpenEdge trimming appserver

Tags: progress-4gl, openedge

I would like to overwrite (hotfix) .r files that may be in use on a server. Would trimming an appserver to apply these changes be equivalent to shutting down and starting an appserver? Is there any harm in trimming an appserver frequently multiple times? Is there any harm in trimming an appserver even if it is not being utilized?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. Trimming is safe and sufficient.

When clients have bound connections however, those agents will not shut down using trimming and will not get the new r-code.

Comment: Ok that's good to hear. Is the only way for them to get the new r-code to restart the appserver then?

Comment: You can force a stop or kill of individual agents with -agentstop or -agentkill. Thus possibly no need to restart.